# Can I pass variable to fitnesse test case through restful services?

Tags: fitnesse

I am automating the fitnesse execution , so that the test case can be called from code.
Now these test case are dependent on some variable I have defined in wiki. Can I specify the value of variables in wiki through RestFul services ? Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can, read data from any source thru fixture code and save result as variable.

- create fixture
- read data into fitnesse variable
- use var in other fixters